# Can't change Application Type RESTClient Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

[image: Picture of my RESTClient on Pentaho Data Integration]

I'm trying to call data from a REST API, so I use RESTClient on Pentaho Data Integration version 9.4, but somehow I can't change or declare the application type into something that I want, it greyed out and I can't selected it.

Please Help

I've found that if I change the HTTP Method to something else, I can change the application type, but I need the HTTP Method to be GET Method so I can't change it to be anything else other than GET, but then because of that, I can't change the Application Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The GET method refers to a HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) method
> that is applied while requesting information from a particular source.
> It is also used to get a specific variable derived from a group.

When you select the `HTTP Method = GET` in Pentaho, it expects to receive data from the REST API server. It is not meant to send data to the server in a particular format, so the `Application Type` section is disabled. In the REST Client Step, the `Application Type` is linked with the `Body Field` as an indication of what type of body/data is sent to the REST API server. In the case of `HTTP Method = POST / PUT /...`, the API server expects the body data and hence it is enabled. This is **not** an issue in the Pentaho step.

Alternatively, If you are expecting to receive the data from the REST server in a particular format using the GET method, you can always add it as an additional argument/filter as below:

```
http://<rest API server>/getData?name=XYZ&xml=Y
```

The above call uses the `GET` method to fetch the data and expects the format to be in XML. However, it also depends on the way your API server is sending back the request. I would suggest looking into your API server for documentation reference on using GET requests.

[Official Pentaho REST Client documentation](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.5/Products/REST_Client) for reference.

Comment: Oh so that's why.
I'm actually expecting to receive data from the REST API, but I guess I'm using it in the wrong way.
Thank you so much for the answer and for the solution, I really appreciated it

Comment: @YanuarAudiNugraha Please accept the answer if this solves your query in SO.